# Is it feasible to do a Yu-Gi-Oh! booster draft?

Tags: house-rules, yu-gi-oh

*Magic: The Gathering* has a [Booster Draft](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/formats/booster-draft) format in which each player opens a booster pack, picks a card to keep, then passes the rest to the next player. After this is repeated a number of times, players add basic lands so that they have a deck they can use in a tournament. The designers of new Magic sets make sure that the cards and their distributions will be fun to play in a Booster Draft.

Is it feasible to do a booster draft with similar rules in the *Yu-Gi-Oh!* card game? If I have players open booster packs and pass them around following the same rules as the Magic Booster Draft format, would it create playable decks and a satisfying experience?

<sub>I'd prefer an answer based on experience from someone who has attempted this. If nobody has tried it, I will accept a detailed analysis of why it would or would not work.</sub>

Comment: Given that there's an [article describing how it works](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Draft_Format) why would you assume you can't do this?

Comment: For added bonus, here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELbB02Jsnsk) of a designer at Konami walking you through a draft.

Comment: @corsiKa I didn't know that the article existed; I'm not super familiar with the *Yu-Gi-Oh!* card game. Now that I look at it, I see that it is says that it is missing "Battle Pack-specific rules", but don't know what that means. Given that there's a video of a Konami designer, does that mean it's an official format, as opposed to just some fan rules? The wiki article doesn't say.

Comment: @Thunderforge Battle Pack Specific rules apply to Draft Tournaments made with any Battle Pack (1, 2, or 3) expansion. In the answer I posted there is a link to one BP expansion where such rules are explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it is feasible**. It is not so different from other Card Game Drafts, and it is briefly described [here](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Draft_Format).

However, from experience, it is not fully feasible to do with *any* booster pack, and is especially difficult with the "main" Card Expansion Sets that follow the Anime, which usually are 100-card sets or less. In fact, I have never seen a Draft tournament made on such "main" expansion sets in the community I play.

If you plan to do a Draft tournament **I suggest you consider doing it with card expansions like [Battle Pack 3: Monster League](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/products/bp-bp03.html), its previous versions, or similar boosters.** That link also describes on detail how to carry out such tournaments.

These Battle Pack sets are specifically made for draft or sealed pack tournaments, as they include a **wide and balanced variety of cards**. These are also **bigger card set expansions** (BP3 has 237 cards) which enable for a better gameplay. They also tend to be **cheaper by the booster**, something that makes it easily to afford and convince prospect duelists to join the tournament.

Answer (score 0):

The only issues that I see is that the first player to open the pack will likely pull the one "good" card, and Yugioh also has many cards that rely on other cards (ie Trickstar Light Stage is useless w/o other Trickstar monsters). Konami has a set formula of distributing cards of increasing rarity in packs and boxes. I don't know if Magic follows a similar formula. I believe it would be both feasible and an interesting challenge to a player. It certainly wouldn't be the most competitive deck, but it should be a fun time by all.

Comment: Magic does, plus in a draft, everyone opens packs, the way it works in magic is each player in the draft pod opens a pack, takes one card then passes the pack, so everyone should have the same chance at access to the high rarity card, since everyone gets first access to the same number of packs. In magic every drafter gets 3 packs to open.